# Field Security: how to make it possible to edit a field when creating a record, then make it read only for editing?

Tags: security, salesforce

We'd like to make it possible for our users to fill out the lead source field when creating a record, but after it has been created, lock the field so only an admin can edit it. How can I do this?

Comment: You could add some more details, including code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a code solution if your purpose is just what you described. You should go for a validation rule on the object. Here is one that will work for your purpose:

```
AND(
NOT(ISNEW()),
ISCHANGED(LeadSource),
$Profile.Name  <> "System administrator"
)
```